# Woocommerce myaccount add tab not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add more than one tab to my myaccount page. I've searched in Stackoverflow questions about this topic and I found something and I've did it like they said but don't get content from my given .php file.

This is the code:

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' ); 

function my_custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items = array(
        'dashboard'           => __( 'Mein Account', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'              => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
 'meine-trainingsplaene'    =>     'Meine Trainingspläne', //New Tab!!
 'meine-ernaehrungsplaene'  =>     'Meine Ernährungspläne', //New Tab!!
        //'downloads'           => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
 'motivationstipps'            =>     'Motivationstipps', //New Tab!!
        //'edit-address'        => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'payment-methods'     => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'edit-account'        => __( 'Edit Account', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'customer-logout'     => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' ); 

add_action( 'init', 'add_wc_endpoint' );
function add_wc_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'meine-trainingsplaene', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
 add_rewrite_endpoint( 'meine-ernaehrungsplaene', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
 add_rewrite_endpoint( 'motivationstipps', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 0 );
function my_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'meine-trainingsplaene';

    return $vars;
}

function my_custom_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_custom_flush_rewrite_rules' ); //wp_loaded becuase I don't have to reactivate the template (found on Stackoverflow)

function my_custom_endpoint_content() {
    include '../../plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/meine-trainingsplaene.php'; //I've tried it with ../../ to go back from my theme folder to get the new file path plugins/woocommerce etc. but no effekt
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_meine-trainingsplaene_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content' );
```

Comment: do you have this plugin ../../plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/meine-trainingsplaene.php placed properly in the directory ?

Comment: Here you have the official related documentation (not very known): https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/2.6-Tabbed-My-Account-page

Comment: @SurendraPatil This is not a Plugin! Just my one page named meine-trainingsplaene.php